# How to retrieve data from sql query and use it in my javascript function

Tags: javascript, sql, ajax, json, codeigniter

I have a form like this (which is inside a CodeIgniter View page):

```
 <form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin_logins/regis2" onsubmit="return checkTime();" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <legend id="registration_legend">Registration</legend>
                <div>
                    <label id= "std_id_add_label">Student ID:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="std_id" id = "student_id_add" placeholder="Student ID" required="1"/>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <label id= "is_member_add_label">Member?</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name ="is_member_checkbox" class ="membercheck" checked="checked" value="1" onchange="valueChanged()"/>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div id = "privilege_code">
                    <label id= "privilege_code_add_label">Privilege Code:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="privilege_code" id = "privilege_code_add" placeholder='0'/>
                </div>

  </form>
```

And I have a Javascript like this:

```
    <script>        
    function checkTime()
    {           
        var today = new Date();
        var hour = today.getHours();
        if(hour < '17')
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Sorry, registrations are closed after 5 pm.");
            location.href = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin_logins/registration';
            return false;
        }
    }       
    </script>
```

All I want to do is something like this:

```
   <script>     
    function checkTime()
    {           
        var today = new Date();
        var hour = today.getHours();
        //alert(hour);
        if(hour < '17')
        {
            //well I want something like the following 
            query = select count(std_id) from registration where std_id = document.getElementById("student_id_add") and date = today
            if(query > 1)
            {
                alert("You are already registered.");
                return false; 
            }
            else
            { 
                return true;
            }
        }
        //don't worry about the above syntax, I know it's wrong and I'm looking for the right  stuff
        else
        {
            alert("Sorry, registrations are closed after 5 pm.");
            location.href = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/admin_logins/registration' ;
            return false;
        }
    }       
</script>
```

If count of `std_id` is more than one on submit, means if there is an existing `std_id`, then data will not be submitted.

On form submit, data will go to this controller method-

```
  function registration_add
  {
      if($_POST)
      {
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dacca');
        $rdata['std_id'] = $this->input->post('std_id');
        $rdata['entry_date'] = date('Y-m-d');
        $rdata['is_member'] = $this->input->post('is_member_checkbox');
        $rdata['privilege_code'] = $this->input->post('privilege_code');

        $res = $this->registration_model->insert_registration($rdata);
        if($res)
        {   
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Registration information added successfully');
            header('location:'.base_url()."index.php/admin_logins/regis");
        }
      }
      else
      {
        $this->load->view('admin_logins/registration_add');
      }   
  }
```

And model method -

```
public function insert_registration($data)
{
    return $this->db->insert('registration', $data);
}
```

My database is MySQL and my table name is `registration`, structure as follows:

```
      Columns                 Data Types
        id                     int PK
       std_id                 varchar(15)
     entry_date                 date
     is_member                  int
   privilege_code            varchar(12)
```

I want to know:

1. What is the correct way to do this? (I heard about using ajax, however, any solution is welcome.)
2. What is the correct syntax and code placements?

Comment: You can post your form using ajax ($.post).
Then, the php script should send response as json data (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Javascript can deal with JSON data

Comment: I am a beginner and I am very weak in ajax. Please give me a detailed answer.

Comment: Have a look at :
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery 

The second is mor usefull

Comment: Please try to understand that it's an emergency problem I'm facing. I need a solution first, I can go through tutorials and documentations later.

Comment: Well, I can see someone gave this question a downvote, without caring to explain to me what's wrong with my post, let alone helping me. That's really very rude.

Answer (score 0):

May be its too late, but i think it will help you..

This is just a ajax request.
In the view file

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type    : "POST",
    url     : "<?php echo site_url('route_name'); ?>",
    data    : {
                 "key" : value
              },
    success: function(result,status,xhr){
        if(result.length > 0) {
             msg = JSON.parse(result);
             // do your work here.

        },
    error: function(xhr,status,error){
        alert('Error Occurred.');
    }
});
```

In the controller

```
    // AJAX
    function ajax_function()
    {
        $this->load->model('model_name');
        echo json_encode($this->model_name->model_function($this->input->post('key')));
    }
```